# Советы будущему специалисту по информационной безопасности в 2021

Tags: linux, безопасность

Какие основные советы вы могли бы дать **специалисту** по **ИБ** в **2021**?
В чем заключается суть вопроса, чтобы на него был достоверный и полный ответ: будучи студентом, который учиться на ИБ и хочет устроиться специалистом в этой сфере не в своей стране, каким лучшим образом ему подготовитсья для этого? Нужно ли сильно углубляться в различные законы именно этой (опреленной страны) касательно стандартов и прочего? Что вообще как специалист, работающий в сфере ИБ вы можете сказать? (Здесь рассматриваются все: от работы тестировщика до серьезной защиты скажем банковских данных и прочего)

Comment: учите английский. серьезно.

Comment: да да, и русский тоже:)

Comment: @KoVadim как вы считаете, будет ли достаточно знаний у студента, заканчивающий гос. университет по этой специальности или же обязательно нужно проходить какие - то онлайн курсы? Может знания и опыт прибавятся уже с опытом работы, как думаете?

Comment: экспериментируйте и самообучайтесь. Никакие онлайн курсы не научат. гос.университет дает немного другое.